# Django REST framework: data not posting to database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i've been banging my head against a wall for a good few hours, thinking I understoodthe django rest framework but I clearly don't. when I try adding an entry via the todo-create api it gives me `{'list_item': None, 'complete': False}`

when I print the serializer without the .data it recognises that there was something inputted into the list_item, but it won't send to the database:

```
TodoSerializer(data=<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': ['    {\r\n        "list_item": "test item",\
r\n        "complete": false\r\n    }']}>):
    list_item = CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    complete = BooleanField(required=False)
```

I am also getting the following in the terminal:

```
Method Not Allowed: /project2/todo/todo-create/
[14/Sep/2020 23:49:55] "GET /project2/todo/todo-create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 8987
```

View.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TodoSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls = {
        'List': '/todo-list/',
        'Detail View': '/todo-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create': '/todo-create/<str:pk>/',
        'Update': '/todo-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete': '/todo-delete/<str:pk>/',
    }

    return Response(api_urls)

@api_view(['GET'])
def todoList(request):
    todo = Todo_list.objects.all()
    serializer = TodoSerializer(todo, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
@api_view(['GET'])
def todoDetail(request, pk):
    todo = Todo_list.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TodoSerializer(todo, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def todoCreate(request):
    serializer = TodoSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        print("issue with data")
    print(serializer.errors)
    print(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def todoUpdate(request, pk):
    todo = Todo_list.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TodoSerializer(instance=todo, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Third party
    'storages',
    'rest_framework',

    # Unique
    'projects',
    'reddit_app',
    'todo_app',
    'language_learn',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'personal_portfolio.urls'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Todo_list(models.Model):
    list_item = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_item
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Todo_list

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo_list
        fields = ('list_item', 'complete')
```

I know it has something to do with authentication but I can't figure out what exactly.

If the solution is obvious then I apologise, I started learning the framework a few days ago and I just need someone to check over the code to see where the stupid is.

Answer (score 1):

Your `todoCreate(request)` method is restricted to POST requests only using `@api_view(['POST'])` decorator and from your terminal's output we can see that you are trying to make a GET request. Your terminal is saying `Method Not Allowed` because `get()` method is not allowed. Try again using POST method for that url this time.

Comment: So that's fixed the `Method Not Allowed issue`. however the list_item is still being sent as null.

Comment: I've just tested the code and it seems to be working fine, I'm not facing the problem. Have you checked if the entry has been recorded to the database correctly? What does the `print(serializer.errors)` say? You can pass the argument like `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: `print(serializer.errors)` is just showing an empty dict.

Comment: So after some reading I believe this may have something to do with it: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/
There is a section for serializer fields: _"Note that, without an explicit default, setting this argument to True will imply a default value of null for serialization output, but does not imply a default for input deserialization.
Defaults to False"_. 
This I believe is referring to being able to read/write via the api?

Comment: So This still hasn't resolved the issue, so I have no idea where to even look to fix this